# Import Multiple Csvs into Single Table

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to use the code below to import multiple csvs into one table. For some reason it imports all csvs but creates a separate table for each instead of importing into the UKR table.

I'm using Access 2016 and UKR is a blank table with no field names or data.

Can anyone see what the issue is?

Thanks

```
    Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Function DoImport()

Dim strPathFile As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

blnHasFieldNames = True

strPath = "C:\UKR\"

strTable = "UKR"

strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")


Do While Len(strFile) > 0
      strTable = Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 4)
      strPathFile = strPath & strFile
      DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

      strFile = Dir()

Loop


   MsgBox "done"


End Function
```

Comment: What do you mean by table has no field names? Table must have fields to receive data from import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because code is resetting the destination table within the loop. Remove line

`strTable = Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 4)`